# SQL selecting a single record by comparing the different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My problem is the following..

[image]

The help that I need is to only SELECT when both prp_response <> 1 for each of prp_hist_id
so it will list those ones (DISTINCT)

For example in this case will only SELECT only the prp_hist_id = 21 since both prp_response <> 1

Hope I was clear enough and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT prp_hist_id
FROM tbl_proposal_workload
WHERE prp_hist_id NOT IN ( SELECT prp_hist_id FROM tbl_proposal_workload WHERE prp_response = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer, but specific to your case is the use of `GROUP` to choose diferent values and `HAVING` to discard the case that contain the prp_reponse=1

```
SELECT prp_hist_id
FROM tbl_proposal_workload
GROUP BY prp_hist_id
HAVING MIN(prp_response)<>1
```

Hope it helps!